# cobertura-instrument.sh fails to instrument jar file with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I'm trying to instrument jar file (from Spacewalk project) so I can measure code coverage of mine testing, but it is failing:

```
# /opt/cobertura-2.1.1/cobertura-instrument.sh --datafile /tmp/out /usr/share/rhn/lib/rhn.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:432)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
Could not find the main class: net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.InstrumentMain.  Program will exit.
```

I have tried to provide one random class (in the ideal state I want to instrument all of them) from that jar as well, but with same result:

```
# jar tf rhn.jar | tail
org/cobbler/CobblerConnection.class
[...]
# /opt/cobertura-2.1.1/cobertura-instrument.sh --datafile /tmp/out /usr/share/rhn/lib/rhn.jar org.cobbler.CobblerConnection
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something what it is trying to tell me.

I'm using **cobertura-2.1.1** downloaded from SourceForge and extracted into `/opt`, running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this was simple:

```
# dos2unix /opt/cobertura-2.1.1/cobertura-instrument.sh
```

also it is missing bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash`), so you might need to add it to the beginning of the file (I do not know why it worked for me even without that).